# using MS Access 2007,

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am doing a project in MS Access 2007 where I am going to count the number of absences of each student.  This will be the table:

```
name of student | absent1 | absent2 | absent3 | absent4 | absent5 | total

ryan llorcanuada| 05-7-12 | 05-8-12 | 05-9-12 |________ | _______ | 3
```

The maximum number of absences of each student is 5. So based from the table, the student got only 3 absences and the remaining fields are blank. Supposedly, the table will display 3 in the total field. How am I going to do that? What if the student has no absences?

Comment: Your question has absolutely nothing to do with Windows. It's about MS Access (specifically Access 2007), and that's how it should be tagged. Using the proper tags helps you get attention from people familiar with those topics, and helps you get answers more quickly. Please try and use tags appropriate to your question. Thanks. :)

Comment: :) thanks.. yes for homework..

Answer (score 0):

So, is the question "What is the best way to design a table to store absences?" or is it "Given the following table, how can you calculate the number of absences a student has?"

I ask because the table as shown is a very bad way to structure your database.  To solve the problem with this structure, you are probably going to have to use a series of IIF functions.  Please try something and post what you've tried, then people can help you fix your answer.

Comment: its how can you calculate the number of absences given that table? :)

Comment: Investigate IIF().  And possibly look for a different instructor.